# Ventana modal selección de usuario!

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, modal

Buen día!

Tengo un botón **Eliminar** dentro de un GRID, este grid tiene un evento **OnRowCommand** que elimina dicho registro. El tema es que quiero mostrar un mensaje de confirmación a través de una ventana modal de Boostrap 4.5 cuando el usuario presione el botón eliminar. Este modal tiene dos botones Si/No

Dentro del botón eliminar yo llamo una función para mostrar el modal

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showModal(event) {
$("#mEliminar").modal();
return false;            
};
</script>
```

el botón es:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnEliminar" runat="server" Text="Eliminar" CssClass="btn btn-danger" OnClientClick="return showModal();" CommandName="Eliminar" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("valor") %>'/>
```

Cuando presiono Eliminar, el modal se abre correctamente, sin embargo no se como es la lógica para desde la funcion pasarle al **OnClientClick** del botón un **True** cuando el usuario seleccione **Si** del modal